# updating Textbox.text in serverside code asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox in my default.aspx page that I want to update it's text property in an event handler but the change does not take place after executing the code .

```
void _gsc_Task_Completed(object sender, TaskEventArgs e)
{

  TextBox1.Text = "New Value";


}
```

How ever , if I do this on the click event of a simple button the textbox.Text value
changes.

what is the difference between a custom event handler like _gsc_Task_Completed and a simple button click event ?

Comment: where are you calling `_gsc_Task_Completed` ?

Comment: this event is raised in a class library when a task is completed and I want to change the textbox.text in the _gsc_Task_Completed event handler

Comment: did you debug this ? is _gsc_Task_Completed is ever getting called ?

Comment: Yes , I even manually run the code in vs debugger , but nothing happens ... I just need to refresh the page with the new textBox value

Comment: that depends on when your event handler is exactly being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text box is a `server side control`. when you change the text this work(change text)  is client side so the event `not firing`. but when i click on a button the page is going to server and back so the event `is firing.`

Comment: _gsc_Task_Completed is firing but I want to refresh the page with the new textbox value

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the page lifecycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Either your event handler is being called to early (and clobbered by whatever is brought back from the client) or it is being called after the control was already rendered.

If I were you I'd put a breakpoint there as well as normal handlers for page onInit, onLoad, etc. See what order that handler is called (if at all) and what is below it on the callstack.